# USB tethering not working Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, usb, tethering

I have a `Samsung S7 Edge` & I was trying to use `USB tethering` but it's not working.

Under Network I'm seeing `USB Ethernet` but it says cable unplugged while it's not.

When I use `sudo ifconfig` I'm not seeing the new network.
Any ideas why it's not working?

NB: USB tethering does on my windows 10 partition.

#### Edit:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This should go out of the box, try to add your user account to the dialout group with `sudo usermod -aG dialout $USER` then reload your user session

Comment: Thanks cmak.fr I did the changes & restarted but it still doesn't work.